# How to create an array of booleans in arm assembly?

Tags: gcc, arm, armv7

I need to specify each boolean manually like in a fixed table, so using 
Array: .skip 400

I will be declaring an array of 400 bytes,so how can i set the boolean values?

Answer (score 0):

Boolean variables in C and C++ are basically treated as a native integer assigned 1 for true and 0 for false; in ARM's case it would be a 32-bit integer. So if you need to access the structure as an array of `Booleans` in C/C++ you would need to access them as 32-bit integers aligned on a 4-byte boundary. However if you only need to access it from other assembly code you can use each byte as it's own `boolean` variable and simply manipulate the array on a byte level.

In ARM assembly, this would be the difference between accessing the array with `LDR` vs with `LDRB`.

Answer (score 0):

ARM registers are 32 bits each.  You only need a bit to represent a boolean.  So you can use the following 'C' code to access an array,

```
uint32_t load_bool(uint32_t index)
{
    return (bool_array[index>>2] & (1<<(index&3)));
}

void store_bool(uint32_t index, int value)
{
    uint32_t target = bool_array[index>>2];
    if(value)
     target |= (1<<(index&3));
    else
     target &= ~(1<<(index&3));

    bool_array[index>>2] = target;
}
```

Use a compiler to target your CPU; for instance tuning [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/DKy8R2) output on a Cortex-A5 gives,

```
load_bool(unsigned int):
        ldr     r3, =bool_array
        mov     r2, r0, lsr #2
        ldr     r3, [r3, r2, asl #2]
        and     r0, r0, #3
        mov     r2, #1
        and     r0, r3, r2, asl r0
        bx      lr
store_bool(unsigned int, int):
        ldr     r3, =bool_array
        mov     r2, r0, lsr #2
        cmp     r1, #0
        ldr     r1, [r3, r2, asl #2]
        and     r0, r0, #3
        mov     ip, #1
        orrne   r0, r1, ip, asl r0
        biceq   r0, r1, ip, asl r0
        str     r0, [r3, r2, asl #2]
        bx      lr
```

The instructions `tst`, `bclr`, etc might be useful if you choose a macro instead of a function call (bit index known at compile/assemble time).  Also, `ldrb` or byte access might be better on older platforms/CPUs.  Most ARM CPUs have a 32bit bus, so the cycles for `ldrb` and `ldr` are equal.